# GWT and getClass().getPackage()

Tags: gwt

I'm getting this error at runtime when I try to use getClass.getPackage().getImplementationVersion(), in my FooterViewImpl class, to show my project's version number (from the pom.xml file) on the web page. I think the error is from the gwt java-to-javascript compiler.

```
[ERROR] [OnlineGlom] - Line 52: The method getPackage() is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends FooterViewImpl>

java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'org.glom.web.client.ClientFactory' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
```

Should I expect this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`getPackage()` is not emulated by GWT: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation. The motto of GWT is to do the maximum at compile-time rather than runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestion for how to get that information from the pom.xml file at compile time?

Comment: Call getImplementationVersion from a [GWT generator](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#generators)?